# Unable to resolve module react-navigation from

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I got an Error
Unable to resolve module react-navigation from E:\Dog-Health\routes\homeStack.js: react-navigation could not be found within the project.

I installed the packages as sad the instruction here :
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started

I installed  @react-navigation/stack :

yarn add @react-navigation/native

my dependencies in package.json :

```
 "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.10",
"@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.4",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.5",
"expo": "~41.0.1",
"expo-status-bar": "~1.0.4",
"react": "16.13.1",
"react-dom": "16.13.1",
"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-41.0.0.tar.gz",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.10.2",
"react-native-reanimated": "~2.1.0",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "3.2.0",
"react-native-screens": "~3.0.0",
"react-native-web": "~0.13.12"
```

cant get what the problem is i tried to rebuild the project and its still don't help

Comment: Try deleting the node_modules folder and do npm install again.

Comment: did you find the solution?